# how to retrieve value from dynamic html form elements in servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

How can I retrieve value from input elements that are generated dynamically using servlet?

Here's an example:

```html
<label>Name your </label><input type="text" name="values[]">
<input type="button" value="Add More" onClick="addXYZ();">
```

it can be retrieved using :

```
String val[]=request.getParameterValues("values[]");
```

now having problem in

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="uploadfr">
<input  type="file" name="filed[]" accept="image/*" required>
 <input type="submit" value="upload">
 </form>
```

how can i retrieve images in servlet?

Comment: Please add your research and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Like any other parameter sent to server: by its `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking for something similar to:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var addXYZ = function() {
    var retrievedValue = document.getElementsByName("values[]")[0].value;
    alert(retrievedValue);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<label>Name your </label><input type="text" name="values[]">
<input type="button" value="Add More" onClick="javascript:addXYZ()">
</body>
<html>
```